# Value selected in Picker, working on ANDROID but not on iOS

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-hooks, picker

I am making forms with select using the library @ react-native-picker / picker.

When selecting a value on Android, the value is selected and is set normally within the constant.

However, when using iOS the value is set within the constant, but is not selected and returns to the default index.

Follow my short code for better understanding.

```
 import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker';

 const [subcategoria, setSubcategoria] = useState([]);

 const [subcategorias, setSubcategorias] = useState([
        {key:'0', nome: 'Default'}, 
        {key:'1', nome: 'Guindaste veicular'}, 
        {key:'2', nome: 'Guindaste Esteira'}, 
        {key:'2', nome: 'Guindaste Munk'}, 
        {key:'4', nome: 'Guindaste Torre '}, 
    ]);

  let subcategoriaItem = subcategorias.map((v, k) => {
    return <Picker.Item key={k} value={v} label={v.nome}/>
  })


 // function to check if any values have been selected. 
function SelectDefaultSubcategory(v,i) {
    if (v.key !== 0) {
       setSubcategoria(v);
    }  

 }

    return (

            <Text style={styles.tituloInput}>SUBCATEGORIA</Text>
            <View style={styles.picker}>
                <Picker
                selectedValue={subcategoria}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => 
                SelectDefaultSubcategory(itemValue,itemIndex)}
                style= {{color: '#fff'}}
                dropdownIconColor={'white'}
                >
                    {subcategoriaItem}
                </Picker>
            </View>

            )
```

SOLUTIONS TRIED

- I tried to install podinstall, however, I use expo and apparently it would not be necessary to use it.
- I tried to test the seledtedValue and selectedItem attributes inside the picker, both went wrong.
- Until the time I only tested it on the emulator, I didn't get to test it on the physical phone.

Does anyone know what could cause this problem?

Comment: What do you pick with this picker? A color? A date?

Comment: @blackapps, subcategories from a form.  But in this case its just a code summary.